# How to install Python 3.8.1 on RHEL 8 UBI container with dnf?

Tags: python, fedora, rhel

How do I install and run Python 3.8.1 on Linux?  Python.org does not offer a Linux binary for Python 3.8.1.

---

I want to type:

`dnf -y install python` or `dnf -y install python38`

and have it install Python 3.8.1 on my RHEL 8.0 or 8.1 inside my minimal container that I want to keep small.

How would I make this happen?

I don't even see a download for Python for Linux on python.org.

---

Do people use Python on Linux?

There are no Linux binaries to be downloaded from Python.org

---

I have searched all over (internet search), and cannot find a way to install Python 3.8.1 easily on a minimal container.

I do not want to download the source and compile, because it is a small container that I am trying to keep small without a lot of overhead.

---

**Reference:**

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-381/

Comment: There definitely are [linux downloads](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/)

Comment: It's probably worth using virtual environments or something similar as well. I personally like Conda.

Comment: The link sent: "There definitely are linux downloads" is a list of source code tarballs.  This is not what I am looking for.  I am looking for compiled binaries for Linux, I'm not sure why you posted this link.  You posted a link to the source code claiming it was a linux binary download.

Comment: Conda is bloat.  Big big big bloat.  The use case is that I am working with, is a container that I wish to keep small and free of bloat.  I simply want to add a repo containing a binary version of Python 3.8.1, and then run: #dnf -y install python or #dnf -y install python38.

Comment: Furthermore, if I did use Virtualenv, where would it pull Python 3.8.1 from? and how?

Answer (score 3):

Two notes: I'm not sure how your container is set. You've tagged this as both RHEL and Fedora. These are two separate distributions. I can comment on Fedora.

Firstly, yes, Python is heavily used in the GNU/Linux world. Most distros use it as one of the languages to build the system and its packages. Linux servers are the only officially recommended servers for Python, or so I've read (will edit with source later if I can find it). Python.org does have Linux downloads, but in source files, packaged in compressed tarballs. This can promote searching the distro package manager first for distro compatibility (since being in a distro's repo should mean the version was vetted); these packages are precompiled unless otherwise specified. It also means the files are distro agnostic -- no need for .DEB, .RPM...

Fedora: There isn't a Fedora version listed in the post, but at least Fedora 31 has a development version, as they call it, of Python 3.8.1 in RPM format. (Fedora 32 is slated to have Python 3.8 at the system level.) You can get it with:

```
sudo dnf install python38
```

Be sure not to overwrite the system variables for python or python3; this mistake can cause systemic issues of varying magnitude. Once installed, you can create a virtual environment in whichever directory you'd like with:

```
python3.8 -m venv <venv_name>
```

To activate the venv, use:

```
. <path/to/venv>/<venv_name>/bin/activate
```

You can set an alias or symlink for ease. When the venv is activated, Python 3.8.x will be the Python version used when the interpreter is called. You should see your venv_name in parentheses, to the left of your PS1. To deactivate, use:

```
deactivate
```

The venv_name should be removed from the PS1, returning it to normal. Checking the Python version should return the system-level Python version.

If you check your Python version before and after the activation, it should be different.

```
python3 -V
```

This package may or may not have been sent downstream to RHEL. If you have the package available but want the full Python stack, or if it isn't available in RHEL's baseline repos, you may need to grab the source files and [unpack the tarballs](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-381/).

Alternatives are checking other repos, seeing about RPMs that someone else compiled from source, or checking out flatpak (which I haven't done).

Last note: compiling from source shouldn't result in a larger Python binary. You can delete any unnecessary extras, like the original archive file used for compiling, after you've extracted what you need. The action itself will only be stored in volatile memory, not on your disk.

Comment: Maybe also note that many distros do have precompiled packages, but Python.org is not a distribution point for them. For Debian-based systems, look at the official repos, with fallback to unofficial prerelease or custom builds provided by third parties.

Comment: I did elude to these things in the second paragraph, but perhaps more implicitly than explicitly. I've edited for clarity. No concern for Debian-based systems here; this post is only concerned with Red Hat distributions.